# Calling C functions from Objective-C (references and default parameters)

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, parameters, parameter-passing

Is it possible to include a C header file for a dylib into an Objective-C project when the functions for the dylib include references and default parameters.  For example

```
extern "C" {
unit32_t GetThisReference(uint32_t & theRef);
unit32_t ThisFunctionHasDefaults(uint32_t aparm, uint32_t one = 1, uint32_t two = 2);
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: `extern "C"` and default parameters and references make your example look like C++, not C.

Answer (score 4):

References and default parameters are features of C++, not C. You could try compiling the file as Objective C++ (by changing the extension to .mm).

Answer (score 1):

Including C libraries is straightforward as Objective C is merely a superset of plain C. But as far as I know, C functions do not have default values. Are you sure that you don't mean a C++ library? In that case, you may want to call the library functions from an Objective-C++ file.